# Insert a complete list in MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb

I have `List` of complex object and the complex object contains more than two fields. Something like - `{car1, car2, car3}` and car has name and type field

Is there a simpler way of inserting a list of car? Something like

```
DBObject updateObject = new BasicDBObject().append("$push", new BasicDBObject().append("cars", cars)
```

I tried with `$pushAll` and it does not seems to be work. I did bit more research and I found it needs information about mapping and that is one of the reasons why this insertion is failing.

What's the best way to do this insertion into MongoDB? Some sample code or direction would be helpful. Please note this has to be done through Java.

Comment: *"Please note this has to be done through JAVA."*  Please note it is Java.  No need to SHOUT about it.  ;)

Comment: Are you updating the list of cars or overwriting the list of cars?

Comment: I am merely pointing out what is expected here.

Comment: Overwriting list of cars

Comment: It is better to just use an atomic `$set` then instead of `$push` which is quite slow in comparison due to its dynamics. You just `$set` the field to the full subodocument of your cars.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, if you don't want to translate your car objects to DBObjects manually, there are Mapping Frameworks out there. like [Morphia](http://code.google.com/p/morphia/).

Personally, I would just wire up a mapping method manually though. Code could look like this (untested, typos to be expected)

```
BasicDBObject updateObject = new BasicDBObject();
BasicDBList dbCarList = mapCars(cars);
updateObject.append("$push", new BasicDBObject("cars", dbCarList));

...
private BasicDBList mapCars(List<Car> cars) {
  BasicDBList result = new BasicDBList();
  for (Car car: cars) {
    BasicDBObject dbCar = new BasicDBObject();
    dbCar.append("name", car.getName());
    result.add(dbCar);
  }

  return result;
}
```

Update: as Sammaye pointed out in the comments, replace $push with $set for replacing the list. $push will append non-existing elements to the array without removing what's there form before.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. It worked like a charm. Learning something new everyday. Good use of BasicDBList. Thanks