# Save list of objects in mongodb

Tags: java, mongodb

I have list of cars { car1, car2, car3 }  and each car has at least two or more fields. The list is converted to BasicDBList. [Example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13759913/insert-a-complete-list-in-mongodb)

```
DBObject saveObject = new BasicDBObject().append("$push", dbBasicListOfCars);
collection.(car).save(saveObject);
```

It fails to save the list in its own collection and complains about the field cannot start with '$' sign.

How can I push the whole list in a collection? Or do  I have to save individual car in collection?

Comment: I believe it's complaining about your key in that append and saying that that should not start with a $.

Comment: I know that. So how should I resolve the problem :)

Comment: There is a difference between `save` and `update` methods in MongoDB. `$push` operation is for `update` method.

Answer (score 1):

```
new BasicDBObject().append("$push", dbBasicListOfCars);
```

In the above statement, you are trying to insert a key-value pair in DBObject with key as **"$push"** and value as **dbBasicListOfCars**.
MongoDB doesnt allow key to have a '$' hence it is failing.

However, the way you are trying to save is also wrong.

What you need is com.mongodb.BasicDBList, which is a utility class to allow array DBObjects to be created.
BasicDBList only supports numeric keys. Passing strings that cannot be converted to ints will cause an IllegalArgumentException.

```
 BasicDBList list = new BasicDBList();
 list.put("1", "bar"); // ok
 list.put("1E1", "bar"); // throws exception
```

refer : http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/BasicDBList.html

Note: MongoDB will also create arrays from java.util.Lists.

```
DBObject obj = new BasicDBList();
 obj.put( "0", value1 );
 obj.put( "4", value2 );
 obj.put( 2, value3 );
```

This simulates the array [ value1, null, value3, null, value2 ] by creating the DBObject { "0" : value1, "1" : null, "2" : value3, "3" : null, "4" : value2 }.